# Facebook API: Get user profile details

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to grab facebook profile details for a provided facebook login. I have had a look and am overwhelmed with information. Where do I start? I perfer to do things in a RESTful environment, but can't see anything like this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why using REST? Facebook is in the process of deprecating the REST API!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is the Facebook SDK for Php](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)... adding it to your project should be pretty straightforward if you follow the instructions in the lower part of the page.